# Accidently reduced salt in pickling recipe - are these pickles still safe?

Tags: food-safety, salt, fermentation, pickling

A dill pickle recipe called for 1.5 cups vinegar, 1.5 cups water, and 2 tablespoons salt. I doubled the bring, but forgot to double the salt before canning my pickles. I ended up with:

```
3 cups Apple cider vinegar (5% acidity)
3 cups water
2 tablespoons pickling salt
```

Will these pickles still be safe to eat? There is a wide range of vinegar:water:salt ratios online, and I'm not sure what is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that level of salt, I think it was more for flavor rather than curing properties. They'll be safe, but they'll probably taste somewhat flat.

Comment: Wait a minute, you're in The Great Outdoors, Hey!

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton Yep, and that's not the only other one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The vinegar should still introduce enough acidity for it not to matter. A couple of tablespoon is not enough for a brine anyway.